# Reescribir un simple juego sin usar la sentencia "goto"

Tags: revisión-de-código, lua

En una parte del libro que estoy leyendo necesito reescribir un juego de "Laberinto" que usa sentencias `goto` a otro que no las use.

El laberinto es muy sencillo, solo tiene 4 habitaciones y se comienza desde la habitación #1:

```
---------
| 1 | 2 |
---------
| 3 | 4 |
---------
```

Esta es la versión original del libro usando `goto`:

```
goto room1 -- initial room
::room1:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "south" then goto room3
  elseif move == "east" then goto room2
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room1 -- stay in the same room
  end
end

::room2:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "south" then goto room4
  elseif move == "west" then goto room1
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room2
  end
end

::room3:: do
  local move = io.read()
  if move == "north" then goto room1
  elseif move == "east" then goto room4
  else
    print("invalid move")
    goto room3
  end
end

::room4:: do
  print("Congratulations, you won!")
end
```

Y este es mi intento de reescribirlo:

```
local rooms = {}
rooms[1] = {
  south=3,
  east=2
}
rooms[2] = {
  south=4,
  west=1
}
rooms[3] = {
  north=1,
  east=4
}
currentRoom = 1
repeat
  local move = io.read()
  local room = rooms[currentRoom][move]
  if room == nil then
    room = currentRoom
    print("Invalid move")
  elseif room == 4 then
    print("Congratulations, you won!")
  end
  currentRoom = room or currentRoom
until currentRoom == 4
```

En este caso me pareció más adecuado usar `repeat` en vez de un `while` aunque en este caso específico creo que ambos funcionan igual.

¿Mi solución es la más óptima o podría cambiar algo en mi código para mejorarlo?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si, es correcto, la idea es que me ayuden a revisar los que tengan experiencia en Lua y me digan si mi "approach" es correcto o qué puedo mejorar. Mejor actualizo mi pregunta

Comment: No he trabajado nunca en Lua, pero parece que la última línea se podría reducir a `currentRoom = room` porque `room` siempre tendrá un valor válido, ¿no?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si es una opción y creo que la otra opción es dejarla como está y deshacerme de la línea `room = currentRoom` y dejar que la lógica booleana de la última línea haga su trabajo

Comment: `currentRoom = room or currentRoom` se ejecuta más veces: `room = currentRoom` sólo se ejecuta si el movimiento es incorrecto, mientras que la comparación lógica se realizaría en cada iteración (aunque no sé si realmente hay una ganancia tan grande, para un programa tan pequeño realmente no importa), por lo que sería mejor simplificar esa línea

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el código tiene mucha lógica pero hay cosas especificas de Lua que hay que tener en cuenta para tu pregunta.

Para este caso emplee el bucle `while`

```
local curRoom, move, room = 1

while true do
  io.write("Estás en la habitación "..curRoom.." Diga a donde ir: ")
  move = io.read()
  room = rooms[curRoom][move]
  if room == 4 then
    print("En hora buena... ¡Ganaste!"); break -- salimos del bucle while
  end
  curRoom = room or curRoom
end
```

Nota que he declarado las variables locales fuera del bucle esta es una buena práctica en Lua para mejorar el [rendimiento del código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/angulo-de-rebote-de-dos-circulos/169055#169055) y no hay necesidad de que se les asigne algún valor cuando se declaran al inicio.

Con respecto al condicional `if room = nil then..` lo suprimí por que tal como expliqué en este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101218/admiralcloack-lua54-then-expected-near/168907#168907) Lua considera como falso una variable nula o falsa -valga la redundancia- esto puede ser confuso porque incluso podría creerse en primera instancia que una tabla vacía es nula lo cual no es cierto para Lua

```
print(nil or 2)                             -- se imprime: 2
print(1 or 2)                               -- se imprime: 1
local miVar; print(miVar or "otro valor")   -- se imprime: otro valor
print({} or "tb")                           -- se imprime: table: 0x....
```

Esto también puede ser parecido a C# con su [operador ?:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) quedando algo así el ejemplo del enlace

```
local function cal(x) print(x~=0 and math.sin(x)/x or 1) end
cal(0); cal(0.8)
-- se imprime: 1    0.8966951136244035
```

En ese sentido  `curRoom = room or curRoom` seguirá siendo `curRoom = curRoom` sí `room` es `nil` sólo cuando `room` tenga algún valor, la expresión previa se comportará como si fuera `curRoom = room`