# Angulo de Rebote de dos Circulos

Tags: lua, game, 2d, love2d

como puedo calcular el angulo de rebote entre dos círculos...??

uso el siguiente código para comprobar y resolver las colisiones.

```
-- CHECK COLLISIONS BALLS AND RESOLVE ...
function CheckCollisionResolve(a, b)
    local dx = a.x - b.x;
    local dy = a.y - b.y;
    local d = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    local minDist = (a.radius+b.radius);
    local midpointx = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
    local midpointy = (a.y + b.y) / 2;

    if d <= minDist then
        -- RESOLVE POSITION BALLS ...
        a.x = midpointx + a.radius * (a.x - b.x) / d;
        a.y = midpointy + a.radius * (a.y - b.y) / d;

        b.x = midpointx + b.radius * (b.x - a.x) / d;
        b.y = midpointy + b.radius * (b.y - a.y) / d;

        return true;
    end

    return false;
end
```

todo funciona bien, pero si no hay ninguna reacción por parte del angulo no hay un efecto muy satisfactorio o realista al tratar de resolver las colisiones.

este es el código que mueve a los círculos y comprueba las colisiones.

```
-- UPDATE BALLS ...
function update_balls(dt)
    local lenBalls = #balls;

    for i = 1, lenBalls do
        local ball = balls[i];

        -- CALCULATE NEW POSITION ...
        local theta = ball.angle * (math.pi/180.0);
        ball.x = ball.x + ((ball.speed * dt) * math.cos(theta));
        ball.y = ball.y + ((ball.speed * dt) * math.sin(theta));

        -- CHECK BALL COLLISION TO SCREEN HORIZONTAL.
        if ball.x-ball.r < 0 then
            ball.x = ball.r;
            ball.angle = reflectHorizontalAngle(ball.angle);
        elseif ball.x+ball.r > sw then
            ball.x = sw-ball.r;
            ball.angle = reflectHorizontalAngle(ball.angle);
        end

        -- CHECK BALL COLLISION TO SCREEN VERTICAL
        if ball.y-ball.r < 0 then
            ball.y = ball.r;
            ball.angle = reflectVerticalAngle(ball.angle);
        elseif ball.y+ball.r > sh then
            ball.y = sh-ball.r;
            ball.angle = reflectVerticalAngle(ball.angle);
        end
    end

    -- CHECK COLLISIONS BALLS RESOLVE ...
    for i = 1, lenBalls do
        for j = 1, lenBalls do
            if i ~= j then
                local col = CheckCollisionResolve(balls[i], balls[j]);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

este es el código que uso para calcular los ángulos de rebote con las paredes (horizontal y vertical).

```
-- REFLECT ANGLES VERTICAL AND HORIZONTAL ...
local reflectVerticalAngle = function(angle) return (360 - angle) < 0 and ((360 - angle) + 360) or (360 - angle); end;
local reflectHorizontalAngle = function(angle) return (180 - angle) < 0 and ((180 - angle) + 360) or (180 - angle); end;
```

la velocidad de los círculos es constante sin variación, ya que estoy trabajando con ángulos.

espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la solución pasa más en este caso por un tema de geometría y entender como opera el [sistema de coordenadas love2d](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics)

Mira el siguiente esquema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si observas el sistema de referencia del citado SDK toma como punto de partida, la parte superior izquierda del monitor en sentido horario, realmente el diagrama que he mostrado puede hacerse de diferentes formas (triangulo isósceles, paralelas, etc) pero prefiero aplicar la tercera ley de newton... es decir el ángulo con el que va golpear la pared será el ángulo de rebote pero con signo cambiado.

Con respecto al código no sé cuantas pelotitas habrán en la aplicación pero lo que sí te sugiero por la intensidad de cálculo que vas aplicar, declares las variables globales como locales, y que las variables locales las declares fuera del bucle `for` para mejorar el rendimiento del código, quedando algo así:

```
-- Funciones de ayuda
-- deben estar al inicio de todo el archivo
-- es una buena práctica para mejorar el rendimiento
-- del código
local cos=math.cos
local sin=math.sin
local rad=math.rad

-- UPDATE BALLS ...
function update_balls(dt)

    local theta -- no importa que no le asignes valor inicialmente
                -- ya que Lua no requiere que se le defina el tipo
                -- de variable que va ser, es decir puede ser string
                -- y luego convertirse en number esto es sumamente útil, por ejemplo:
                -- local a = "10"; print(type(a)) -- se imprime: string
                -- a = a + 0; print(type(a))      -- se imprime: number

    for _, ball in pairs(balls) do

        -- CALCULATE NEW POSITION ...
        theta = rad(ball.angle)
        ball.x = ball.x + (ball.speed * dt) * cos(theta)
        ball.y = ball.y + (ball.speed * dt) * sin(theta)

        -- el resto del código
    end

end
```