# ¿Por qué este loop no coge 2500 clientes?

Tags: loops, matemáticas, lua

Estoy realizando un código en la que una suma del número inicial se quede en un rango determinado sin superar 10000 ninguno de ellos dos, uno es la suma del primero +123, pero por alguna razon, no salen 2500 resultados (clientes), solamente salen 2459

El numero inicial es 5000, y en ningun momento puede salir de 10.000, la operacion consta de X y X+123, pero solamente he logrado 2439 resultados

Que error ocurre?

```
    clientes = 2500

base = 5000
sumport = 124

portase = {}
    for i=1, clientes do
    str = "no"
    --formula = math.floor(base+((i*sumport)/53)) --2000 clients
    formula = 5000+( ( math.floor( i / 123 ) ) * ( 123 ) ) + (i-1) --New formule
    portase[formula+123] = true
    ASE = formula+123
        if ASE > 10000 then
        break
        end
        if portase[formula] then
        str = "YES YES YES YES"
        end
    ASE = formula+123
    print ("CLIENT: "..i..", PORT: "..formula..", ASE: "..ASE..", MATCHES WITH OTHER? "..str)
    portase[formula] = true
    end
```

Comment: clientes empieza en 0 o en 1???

Comment: clientes empieza en 1, pero no coge 2500 resultados, la operacion lo que hace es intentar hallar que un numero+123 sean 2500 resultados sin que se repita tanto el numero como numero+123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He re-formulado tu código pero he mantenido la fórmula que has empleado con `math.floor` para ver que se obtiene con eso:

```
local clientes = 2500
local limite = 10000 
local base = 5000
local sumport = 123
local portase = {}
local floor, min = math.floor, math.min
local str

for i=1, clientes do

  formula = 5000 + sumport*floor(i/sumport) + (i-1)
  ASE = min(formula+sumport,limite)
  str = ASE == limite and "YES YES YES YES" or "no"
  print ("CLIENT: "..i..", PORT: "..formula..", ASE: "..ASE..", MATCHES WITH OTHER? "..str)

end
```

El código puede resumirse de acuerdo a lo que entiendo que buscas mediante el siguiente esquema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto a los saltos discretos que quieres lograr con la fórmula que empleaste, te sugiero que revises algo de [**aritmética modular**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aritm%C3%A9tica_modular) para que vayas por el camino correcto en el desarrollo de tu código.

Con respecto a la expresión que empleé en `str = ASE == limite and "YES YES YES YES" or "no"` te sugiero que veas este [**post**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6168/reescribir-un-simple-juego-sin-usar-la-sentencia-goto) que hice sobre ese tipo de notación.

Eliminé también de tu código original las siguiente sentencia:

```
if portase[formula] then str = "YES YES YES YES" end
```

Esto porque de acuerdo al orden de ejecución que estaba, siempre tomaría `portase[formula]` el valor de `nil` es decir jamás `str` sería `"YES YES YES YES"`

Ahora si lo que buscas, es que el match sea el ***PORT*** del cliente **"n"** igual al ***ASE*** del cliente **"n-123"**, a partir del Cliente 124 (su **Port:5123** sería igual al **ASE:5123** del Cliente 1 -***ver diagrama de arriba***-) en tal caso el `str` se podría definir también así:

```
str = i>=124 and "YES YES YES YES" or "no"
```

Sería muy sencillo poner un condicional para esa situación también. Realmente la complejidad de tu pregunta reside como lo veo, en la fórmula que emplearás para definir los saltos discretos.

Answer (score 0):

Porque en la iteracion 2460 el valor de `ASE` es igual a 10042 y entra en tu condicion `if` que tiene dentro un `break` esto termina el FOR y no imprime mas valores.

Comment: Ahi la cuestion, no encuentro una solucion para que haya 2500 iteraciones, se queda en 2459 :(

Comment: debes explicar mejor tu pregunta y cambiar tu titulo, ya que solo pides saber por que el loop no llega a 2500, trata de explicar mejor el problema para que te puedan ayudar.