# AdmiralCloack.lua:54: 'then' expected near ')'

Tags: lua, script

```
function Cloaks:Init()
    if (file_exists)(Cloaks.DB) == false) then
        print('Creating Admiral Cloak Database')
        table.save({},Cloaks.DB, FILE_WRITE)
    end
end
```

[image: este error es el que me sale]

Answer (score 2):

El error esta en tu if, suponiendo que todo lo demas esta bien, deberia quedar asi

```
function Cloaks:Init()
    if ((file_exists)(Cloaks.DB)) == false) then
        print('Creating Admiral Cloak Database')
        table.save({},Cloaks.DB, FILE_WRITE)
    end
end
```

te faltaban parentesis

Comment: ok hice la corrección ahora me tira lo mismo en la linea de abajo 
print('Creating Admiral Cloak Database')

Comment: prueba con comillas dobles print("Creating Admiral Cloak Database")

Comment: sigue con el then expected near )

Comment: `function Cloaks:Init()
    if file_exists)(Cloaks.DB  then
        print("Creating Admiral Cloak Database")
        table.save({},Cloaks.DB, FILE_WRITE)
    end     
end` prueba asi

Comment: nada bro sigue igual. . . te envio el archivo completo?

Comment: mandalo y lo reviso, pero el problema esta en tu if, (file_exists)(Cloaks.DB) eso causa el problema pero no se que es

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aTK90LUE

Answer (score 0):

segun https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html
la sentencia if no necesita parentesis:

```
if a<0 then a = 0 end
```

tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function Cloaks:Init()
    if (file_exists)(Cloaks.DB) == false then
        print('Creating Admiral Cloak Database')
        table.save({},Cloaks.DB, FILE_WRITE)
    end
end
```

Comment: ahora sale attemp to call global (file_exists a nil value

Answer (score 0):

tratando de entender un poco la lógica del condicional `if` en tu post, hay que aclara que si se hace en Lua lo siguiente:

```
print((true)(true)) -- asumo que deseas hacer una especie de multiplicación en lugar del operador lógico and
```

Obtendrás un error, creo que la solución podría ir así:

```
local file_exists = "existeArchivo"
local Cloaks = {}

-- Cloaks.DB -- no definido o nil
Cloaks.Init = function()
  if not (file_exists and Cloaks.DB) then print("¡listo!") end
end

Cloaks.Init() -- se imprime: ¡listo!
```

Nota que Lua considera como falso una variable nula o falsa esto puede ser confuso porque incluso podría creerse en primera instancia que una tabla vacía es nula lo cual no es cierto para Lua

```
if {} then print("verdad") end -- se imprime: verdad
```

Answer (score 0):

si lo pones asi?

```
if((file_exists(Cloaks.DB)) == false) then
```