# Lua: función de busqueda y funciones con argumentos opcionales

Tags: funciones, lua, tablas

**Bien, esta es la cuestión:**

quiero hacer una función que permita buscar una *clave* en una tabla, es decir, que la función reciba como argumento el nombre de la clave, no un string, si no el nombre del índice (sin importar su valor) y si este existe, pues... que se almacene en una variable (incluyendo su valor), para luego ser usado y si no existe, pues que imprima un mensaje de error. lo primero que se me ocurre es usar un bloque **for**, el dilema es que no se mucho de programación en lua y no se me ocurre como hacer esto.

la idea de la función debería verse más o menos así
`buscar (indice)`

y la función (usando este ejemplo) debería retornar un mensaje como:
`La clave <indice> tiene el valor: <valor>`
en caso de que dicho índice exista, si no existe, un mensaje de error como:
`El indice <indice> no existe.`

**además:**

me gustaría saber como hacer funciones que tengan argumentos opcionales en Lua.

Espero no sea una molestia y de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo sencillo para abordar tu consulta, es tener en cuenta que Lua trabaja con tablas y a partir de este paradigma se estructuran los datos. Si trabajas con indices o hash puedes tener la siguiente tabla:

```
local datos = {
                    ["carro"]=2018,
                    ["moto"]=2017,
                    ["furgoneta"]=2017
                }
```

Simplemente tendrías que hacer `datos["moto"]` para obtener el valor `2017`. No obstante si realizas la siguiente consulta `datos["yate"]` obtendrás `nil`.
Para esto último se puede implementar una pequeña función:

```
local buscar = function (index, tabla)
    local id, tb = index, tabla
    return tb[id] or "No Encontrado"
end
```

Llamamos la función `buscar` con los siguientes ejemplos:

```
print(buscar("carro", datos)) -- Se imprime: 2018
print(buscar("carr", datos))  -- Se imprime: No Encontrado
```

Nota que la función `buscar` posee la siguiente línea de código `return tb[id] or "No Encontrado"`, la cual es muy similar a: `if ... then ... end`. En este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6168/reescribir-un-simple-juego-sin-usar-la-sentencia-goto/170903#170903) explico en más detalle dicha cuestion.